# JavaScript function to 'get element by parent class' and assign

Tags: javascript, html, css

My predicament is fairly simple: This function gets the `id` of 'this' `<li>` element  based on parent `id` of `<ul>`. It used to work fine but not any more, I will either need to have `<ul>` use `class`es instead of `id` while still being able to assign `id` of 'current' to the current element, or change my css.

```js
function myFunction(element) {
  liArray = document.getElementById("leftlist").childNodes;
  i = 0;
  while (liArray[i]) {
    liArray[i].id = "";
    i++;
  }
  element.id = "current"; // or element.className  ?
}
```

```css
ul#leftlist {
  background-color: rgb(205, 205, 205);
}

ul#leftlist li#current a {
  color: rgb(96, 176, 255);
  background-color: 218, 218, 218);
}

ul#leftlist li a {
  color: rgb(86, 86, 86);
}

#leftlist a:link {
  color: rgb(86, 86, 86);
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#leftlist a:active {
  color: rgb(96, 176, 255);
  background-color: rgb(218, 218, 218);
}
```

```html
<ul id="leftlist">
  <li onClick='myFunction(this);'>
    <a href="123" bla bla </a></li>
  <li onClick='myFunction(this);'> .... etc.</li>
</ul>
```

Perhaps I need to change my css. This worked before but now the current `id` is not being effective as `ul#leftlist li a` takes priority even when i assign `id="current"` via JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

You should use classes for things like "current", not the id. The id normally shouldn't change, and "current" isn't a very good id, as you could have a bunch of things on a page that is "current" in some way. If you need some css style to override another, you can force it with !important:

```
ul#leftlist li.current a {
  color: rgb(96,176,255) !important;
  background-color:218,218,218) !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you using the jQuery framework. It will provide a nice abstraction over your DOM and make it way easier for you to find objects in your DOM and assign events to those objects.

Try reading [this tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery) over at [jQuery.com](http://www.jquery.com). I am sure it will amaze you :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you do need to change one line in your css:

```
ul#leftlist li#current  a{color: rgb(96,176,255);  background-color:218,218,218);}
```

It's missing the `rgb(` after `background-color` and should look like:

```
ul#leftlist li#current  a{color: rgb(96,176,255);  background-color: rgb(218,218,218);}
```

I'd also agree with Erlend, `current` would be better suited to a class.

Answer (score 0):

The function changes to:

```
function myFunction(element){
  var liArray = document.getElementById("leftlist").childNodes;
  var i=0, item;
  while (item = liArray[i++]) {
    if (item.nodeType === 1) {
      item.className = item.className.replace(/(^| )current( |$)/g, '');
    }
  }
  element.className += " current";
}
```

The CSS needs a change to class as well:

```
ul#leftlist li.current a { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you do your change in a way, so that you end up with more than one element having the same id ?-)

That is clearly against the whole idea, using id's they have to be totally unique within the context of the html-document ...

-- the first thing, you ought to do is to be sure you only address your li-elements:

```
liArray=element.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("li");
```

Secondly it could be an idea, to ensure higher priority for one of your selectors by setting something more in the selector:

Highest priority is gained, if you use an inline style-attribute on the tag, but this doesn't seem to be of any use here.

IDs give a high priority, class give a fair priority and element- and pseudo-selectors give a low priority ...

However each type of priority is accumulated and in that way you can give one selector very high priority by preceding it with another of same priority-type:

`ul#leftlist` gives 1 point in high priority and 1 point in low priority

`#myParent ul#leftlist` gives 2 points in high priority and 1 in low

`.myParent ul#leftlist` gives 1 points in high priority, 1 point in fair priority and 1 point in low priority

Thus you can differentiate the priority for your selectors in the stylesheet !-)